# Two textfield with same date picker

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uidatepicker

I have two textfields that I want to input times into.
I've gotten one of the textfields to work so that the inputView is a date picker, however, I can't figure out if there's an easy way to change my code so that the other text field would also have a date picker as the input field.

Here is my code:

```
func createDatePicker(){
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //done button
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    fromTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    fromTextField.inputView = picker


    picker.datePickerMode = .time
    picker.minuteInterval = 15

}
@objc func donePressed(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

    fromTextField.text = "\(dateString)"
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

What would be the best way to make this code work for a toTextField too besides just making a copy of these two functions?

Comment: you can use tags for Textfield and pass object of respective textfield in this function.

Comment: hello why not use datepicker fragment where you can pass textfield

Answer (score 2):

For creating two textFields having same pickerView as inputView @CZ54's answer is correct i.e.

```
func createDatePicker(forField field : UITextField){
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //done button
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    field.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    field.inputView = picker


    picker.datePickerMode = .time
    picker.minuteInterval = 15

}

//later
self.createDatePicker(forField: fromTextField)
self.createDatePicker(forField: toTextField)
```

And to fetch data from pickerView as per the active textField you have to create a variable of type `UITextField` and assign it as following:

```
var activeTextField: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     activeTextField = textField
}
```

And whenever row would be selected in pickerView, by following you could perform relevant actions

```
if activeTextField == fromTextField {
     //action
} else if activeTextField == toTextField {
     //action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
func createDatePicker(forField field : UITextField){
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //done button
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    field.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    field.inputView = picker


    picker.datePickerMode = .time
    picker.minuteInterval = 15

}

//later
self.createDatePicker(forField: fromTextField)
self.createDatePicker(forField: toTextField)
```

Comment: For function donepressed, can it not be called with a field variable also? I'm getting this error: "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer" when I try to call donePressed(forField: field)